# I am trying to make an excel formula that subtracts the 2nd to last number in a column from the last number in the column

Tags: excel-formula

For example H8 -H6 with H7 being blank. Easy =H8-H6. I get that but then there will be rows added and H may have a lot of blank cells but then a number is entered on H15. Now I want H15-H8. Is there an easy way to do this without having to re-do the simple formulas every time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(INDEX(H:H,2):INDEX(H:H,ROW()-1))/(INDEX(H:H,2):INDEX(H:H,ROW()-1)<>""),1))-INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(INDEX(H:H,2):INDEX(H:H,ROW()-1))/(INDEX(H:H,2):INDEX(H:H,ROW()-1)<>""),2))
```

[image]